# How to pass type into Class in SwiftUi?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am new to Swift. I'm trying to make an easy API Manager. I want to use that API like:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct AView: View {
    
    @StateObject var query = Query(url: "/post/id", type: Post.self)
    
    var body: some View {
        if(query.isSuccess) {
           Text(query.data.title)
       }
    }
}
```

I tried this:

```swift
import Foundation
import Combine

class Query: ObservableObject {
    
    let url: String
    let type: Decodable.Type
    
    init(url: String, type: Decodable.Type) {
        self.url = "https://api.domain.com" + url
        self.type = type
    }
    
    @Published var data: type? // ! Error Here: Cannot find type 'type' in scope
    @Published var error: Error?
    @Published var hasError: Bool = false
    @Published var isSuccess: Bool = false
    @Published var isLoading: Bool = false
    @Published var isFetching: Bool = false
    
    private var bag = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    ...
}
```

Everything looks working except passing type to `data`.
How can I pass type to `@Published var data`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making `Query` a generic:

```swift
struct AView: View {

    @StateObject var query = Query<Post>(url: "/post/id")

    var body: some View {
        if(query.isSuccess) {
            Text(query.data?.title ?? "")
       }
    }
}

class Query<T: Decodable>: ObservableObject {

    let url: String

    init(url: String) {
        self.url = "https://api.domain.com" + url
    }

    @Published var data: T?

    // other content as before
}
```

Comment: It works. Thank you :))

Answer (score 0):

I would make Query generic

```
class Query<ResultType: Decodable>: ObservableObject
```

and then pass the result type in the init

```
init(_ : ResultType.Type = ResultType.self, url: String) {
    self.url = "https://api.domain.com" + url
}
```

Some example on how to create a query

```
let query1 = Query(String.self, url: "/post/id")
let query2 = Query<Int>(url: "/post/id")
let query3: Query<Date> = Query(url: "/post/id")
```

Comment: Personal opinion, I would change the type of the `url` property from `String` to `URL` instead.

Comment: Making Query generic worked. Thank you :))